# Looking for a way to vectorize find command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find, vectorization

I am looking for a faster way to use the find command without loops and nothing that I have found so far has helped me. Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
A = [0.1,0.8,1;
     0.3,0.7,1;
     0.2,0.3,1]; % this is a square matrix with cumulated sums of probabilities in its rows
row_sel = [2,3,2]; % this is a vector containing the rows of A that I am interested in
index = NaN(length(A),1);
for i = 1:length(A)
    index(i) = find(A(row_sel(i),:)>rand,1,'first'); % I want to get the index of the first column of row row_sel(i) whose element exceeds a random number
end
```

Unfortunately, something like

```
index_mat = find(A(row_sel,:)>rand(length(A),1),1,'first')
```

does not do the trick. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You random number is different for each `i`. Is that intended? If not, can you post an example without random numbers for clarity? Also, what if there is no such index for some `i`?

Comment: Yes, this is intended and crucial (shocks are uncorrelated across agents in the economy I am modeling). There is an index like this for every i for sure, since the last column of A only contains ones (as the rows contain cumulated sums of probabilities, which in my case also sum to one for each row).

Comment: In your example, `length(A)` is the number of rows or columns, whichever is greater. Perhaps you meant `length(row_sel)`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I should have noted that in my case A always is a square matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare `A` indexed by `row_sel_` with a column vector of random values, exploiting [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/); and then use the second output of [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), which gives the index of the *first* maximum value along the specified dimension:

```
[~, index] = max(A(row_sel,:) > rand(numel(row_sel),1), [], 2);
```

For Matlab before R2016b there is no implicit expanstion, but you can use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
[~, index] = max(bsxfun(@gt, A(row_sel,:), rand(numel(row_sel),1)), [], 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Only that I think it must be `..., rand(length(row_sel),1)), [],2);`

Answer (score 3):

The one-liner:

```
size(A, 2) + 1 - sum(A(row_sel, :) > rand(size(A, 1), 1), 2)
```

**Explanation**

As you already figured out

```
A(row_sel, :) > rand(size(A, 1), 1)
```

gets you the wanted comparison between your values and some random numbers. Let's say this is

```
ans =
    0  1  1
    0  0  1
    0  1  1
```

Then

```
sum(A(row_sel, :) > rand(size(A, 1), 1), 2)
```

counts the occurences of 1s in the result per row, so here it is

```
ans =
    2
    1
    2
```

Now, let's get the total number of elements per row

```
size(A, 2)
```

Just substract the amount of found 1s, and you will get the first index per each row. (We have to add 1, because we want the first occurrence.)

```
size(A, 2) + 1 - sum(A(row_sel, :) > rand(size(A, 1), 1), 2)
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the hint, you are totally right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Great answer, by the way!

Comment: I agree, this is also a great answer, so thanks! LuisMendo's method works a tad faster in my example, which is why I implemented his method in my code now.